# Issue with assemblies in .Net couldnt load file or assembly System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I get the error ,  Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe,  Version=4.0.4.1.

Although I have no reference to that version in the entire solution or any app.config or web.config file as I have upgraded to version 6.0.0.0

Any ideas as to whay it may be happening ?
Are there any nuget packages that depend on the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe that may need to be updated ?

Comment: Please add your .csproj file. Ideally a full [mre].

Comment: i have checked the file no reference to that version. Would there be other dlls that depend on the unsafe that need to be upgraded , or can i view dependencies in Visual Studio ?

Comment: make sure you have enabled ``AutoGenerateBindingRedirects`` in your csproj <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>